# Get page to load as a popup window when user clicks on point on gmap3

Tags: php, jquery, popup, jquery-gmap3

On top of that, I'd really like it to fadeIn as well. My code right now allows me to do all that, but it's not as efficient as I'd like it to be as the PHP pages are loaded right off the bat when the page is loaded. I'd like the .php pages to initially load when the user clicks on the point on the gmap.

Here's some of my code for your digestion:

```
    <?php include("locations/clinton.php"); ?>
```

I know that "include" is the problem, but it won't work at all otherwise. Here's the jquery:

```
latLng: [38.763711, -76.895458],
    data: "<div class='sum'><img src='images/clintonicon.png' width='144' height='144' alt='Clinton' /><p>Clinton, MD 20735<br>Churches: 0<br>Population: 36,208</p></div>",
    options: {
        icon: "images/clintonpin.png"
    },
    events: {
        click: function (marker, event, context) {
            $('#clinton').fadeIn('fast');
            $('.overlay').fadeIn('fast');
        },
        mouseover: function (marker, event, context) {
            var map = $(this).gmap3("get"),
                infowindow = $(this).gmap3({
                    get: {
                        name: "infowindow"
                    }
                });
            if (infowindow) {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                infowindow.setContent(context.data);
            } else {
                $(this).gmap3({
                    infowindow: {
                        anchor: marker,
                        options: {
                            content: context.data
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        mouseout: function () {
            var infowindow = $(this).gmap3({
                get: {
                    name: "infowindow"
                }
            });
            if (infowindow) {
                infowindow.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I try my best to solve things on my own, but when I do need help, I come here. Thanks in advance stackoverflow hive minds.

Comment: Reading code becomes a lot easier with the occasional carriage return and indentation...

Comment: Yes, thank you for doing that for me. I've been too used to reading it in a claustrophobic manner. Researching the initial question I had, though, I still am coming up blank on how to tackle this particular problem. Do I initialize some AJAX? I'm sure that's the solution, perhaps, but I'm not sure how to implement it within gmap. It would be fine if it was a simple jquery .ajax or .load. But something within gmap is not letting it do its thing, or maybe I'm guessing the completely wrong solution. Thus me coming here seeking the answer within the hive mind of you all. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options.  If you want something to open in a traditional "popup" window, then you can simply use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) and point it to the server-side resource you want.  Something like this:

```
click: function (marker, event, context) {
    window.open('http://www.yourserver.com/locations/clinton.php');
}
```

Though from your comment above it sounds like you're looking for something more AJAX-friendly.  Something that shows in more of a modal div than in a popup.  The [jQuery `.load()` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) should be able to handle this with the element(s) you already have.  I can't be exact without knowing your markup, but it might look something like this:

```
click: function (marker, event, context) {
    $('#clinton').load('http://www.yourserver.com/locations/clinton.php', function () {
        $('#clinton').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.overlay').fadeIn('fast');
    });
}
```

You may have to tweak it to match your markup, but the general idea is:

- The `#clinton` element (a `div` perhaps?) already exists on the page, but is empty and hidden.
- The `locations/clinton.php` resource contains only the markup which should be inside of that element.

If you have a lot of these elements then the DOM will build up dynamically as the user clicks on various markers.  If this starts making the page too large then you can also remove these elements as needed:

```
$('#clinton').empty();
```

It's really up to you how you would strike a balance between lots of client-side content and lots of AJAX calls back to the server to re-fetch the same content.

Comment: Yess! Thanks a lot! The AJAX-friendly code worked like a charm! You have more than my utmost gratitude, which I don't even know what that is!